# Check if a string in a cell is a regex in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of strings in a Google Sheet that I want to check if they are valid regex or not and return True/False to the neighboring column. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you provide an invalid pattern to any of the REGEX functions, they will return an error.

[image]

You can take advantage of this to determine whether a given regular expression is valid or not. For example, the following formula returns TRUE if the string in A1 is a valid regular expression and FALSE otherwise.

```cpp
=NOT(ISERROR(REGEXMATCH("",A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Beware! Much random text is a valid regexp, so just putting your name in one of the cells will pass as a valid regexp, so maybe this is not the distinctive separation you were looking for.